# Recommended way to plot a heat map for uneven matrix using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a uneven dataset ready to be plotted in a form of heat map.

The dataset (9 columns, col) looks like this:

```
 col_1 <- runif(100);
 col_2 <- runif(105);
 col_3 <- runif(95);
 col_4 <- runif(102);
 col_5 <- runif(100);
 col_6 <- runif(99);
 col_7 <- runif(97);
 col_8 <- runif(103);
 col_9 <- runif(101);
```

It seems like I need to create an even matrix in order to plot a heat map. However, I hope that I do not need to create some fake data to insert to each column or even to pad some fake data to the end.

I hope that the readings in each column can distribute the heat map without adding other take data using ggplot.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to make a regular matrix, you will need to append some extra values. There are functions which take care of this for you (such as [`rbind.fill`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/rbind.fill)).

Comment: The values in each uneven column are measurements. Appending some extra values to make a even regular matrix should be the last step if I could not find other solutions.

Comment: You can add NA, which are very honest fillers.